# Recyclerview keeps re-populating data from Firebase DB when new child is created

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am currently working on a chat application and have come across an issue. My `Chat Fragment` contains my `Recyclerview` which populates data from `Firebase DB`. I am able to obtain the data, but I am running into an issue. When I open my `Chat Activity` and send a message, a new `push id` is created with the information stored in the child. The data obtained by my `recyclerview` is it gets the last `push id` and retrieves the last message that was sent. The problem is, when I go back into my `fragment`, the recyclerview re-populates and adds the new `push id` last message that was created, and creates another item instead of just refreshing the original item.

So essentially, I will load my app, go into the `Chat Fragment`, my `recyclerview` will display the other user and the last message that was sent, no problem, then I will click on that item, open the `chat activity`, send a message then go back. Now when I am back into the `chat fragment` I will have two or three or however many messages that were sent displaying in the `recyclerview`. Not sure on how to fix this, my code is below:

**DATABASE STRUCTURE**
[image: Database Structure]

> Chat Fragment

```
public class Fragment_MatchChats extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView, mRecyclerViewChat;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mMatchesAdapter, mChatAdapter;
private String currentUserID;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseChat;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_match_chat, container, false);


currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
mDatabaseChat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");
LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerChat = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mRecyclerViewChat = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewChat);
mRecyclerViewChat.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerViewChat.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerChat);

mChatAdapter = new RecyclerViewChatAdapter(getDataSetChat(), getContext());

getUserMatchId();
return v;
}


//this method will get the user ID in the database that you matched with. It will run through the matches child and get all the user IDs
private void getUserMatchId() {
    DatabaseReference matchDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("swipes").child("matches");
    matchDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot match : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    CheckChatID(match.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void CheckChatID(final String chat) {
    DatabaseReference ChatDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("swipes").child("matches")
            .child(chat).child("ChatID");
    ChatDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String ChatID = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                ChatIDExist(ChatID, chat);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void ChatIDExist(final String chatID, final String oppUserID) {
    final DatabaseReference ChatDB = mDatabaseChat.child(chatID);
    final Query lastQuery = ChatDB.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    ChatDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
              lastQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                           String key = child.child("text").getValue().toString();
                           FetchChatInfo(oppUserID,key);

                       }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               });
            } 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void FetchChatInfo(String key, final String chatID) {
    DatabaseReference userDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(key);
    userDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String matched_userID = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                String matches_userName = "";
                String matches_userProPic = "";
                String match_CHATID = chatID;

                if(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue() != null){
                    matches_userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.child("profilePicURL").getValue() != null){
                    matches_userProPic = dataSnapshot.child("profilePicURL").getValue().toString();
                }


                RecyclerViewChatReference chat_obj = new RecyclerViewChatReference(matched_userID, matches_userName, matches_userProPic, match_CHATID);
                resultsChats.add(chat_obj);
                mRecyclerViewChat.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);
                mChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<RecyclerViewChatReference> resultsChats = new ArrayList<RecyclerViewChatReference>();

private List<RecyclerViewChatReference> getDataSetChat() {
    return resultsChats;
}
```

> Chat Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    matchId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("matchID");

    currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID)
            .child("swipes").child("matches").child(matchId).child("ChatID");
    mDatabaseChat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");

    getChatId();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mChatLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mChatLayoutManager);
    mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getDataSetChat(), ChatActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);

    mSendEditText = findViewById(R.id.message);
    mSendButton = findViewById(R.id.send);

    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });


}

private void sendMessage() {
    String sendMessageText = mSendEditText.getText().toString();

    if(!sendMessageText.isEmpty()){
        DatabaseReference newMessageDb = mDatabaseChat.push();

        Map newMessage = new HashMap();
        newMessage.put("createdByUser", currentUserID);
        newMessage.put("text", sendMessageText);

        newMessageDb.setValue(newMessage);
    }
    mSendEditText.setText(null);
}

private void getChatId(){
    mDatabaseUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                chatId = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                mDatabaseChat = mDatabaseChat.child(chatId);
                getChatMessages();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void getChatMessages() {
    mDatabaseChat.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String message = "";
                String createdByUser = "";

                if(dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue()!=null){
                    message = dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue().toString();
                }
                if(dataSnapshot.child("createdByUser").getValue()!=null){
                    createdByUser = dataSnapshot.child("createdByUser").getValue().toString();
                }

                if(message!=null && createdByUser!=null){
                    Boolean currentUserBoolean = false;
                    if(createdByUser.equals(currentUserID)){
                        currentUserBoolean = true;
                    }
                    ChatObject newMessage = new ChatObject(message, currentUserBoolean);
                    resultsChat.add(newMessage);
                    mChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}


private ArrayList<ChatObject> resultsChat = new ArrayList<ChatObject>();
private List<ChatObject> getDataSetChat() {
    return resultsChat;
}
}
```

Comment: try to understand i will give u the answer coz i have faced it alot.

Comment: first of all do one thing try using this method "getUserMatchId();" under the onstart method of the fragment

Comment: then do one thing try to determine which thing is already populated in the recycler view by using "contains" method of array list and restrict this to add populate it again in the recycler view

Comment: @vaibhav I tried the putting it into on start it didn't work, it would add two more items instead of one. The second part you said to do I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: When I close the app and open it again it will be fine. Do you think it would work or be easier if I  just destroy/detach the chat fragment only when I click on my recyclerview and then when I back press on my chat activity it will re-retach it?

Comment: @vaibhavsharma can you explain what you meant with the contains?

Comment: Contains is the method of array list you just check in your list that the elemnt is already exist if it is then restrict to populate using this method